# How to make a custom Maven archetype?

Tags: maven

I am using Maven3 to make a web project based GWT and Spring, How to make custom archetype to include dependencies for both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Guide to Creating Archetypes
>
> Creating an archetype is a pretty straight forward process. An
>   archetype is a very simple artifact, that contains the project
>   prototype you wish to create. An archetype is made up of:
>
> - An archetype descriptor (archetype.xml in directory:
>     src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/). It lists all the files that will
>     be contained in the archetype and categorizes them so they can be
>     processed correctly by the archetype generation mechanism.
> - The prototype files that are copied by the archetype plugin (directory:
>     src/main/resources/archetype-resources/)
> - The prototype pom (pom.xml
>     in: src/main/resources/archetype-resources)
> - A pom for the archetype
>     (pom.xml in the archetype's root directory). Note: this mini-guide has
>     been written for archetype plugin version 1.0.x, with its old
>     archetype descriptor (stored in archetype.xml file). Archetype plugin
>     2.0.x is a new generation that fully supports archetypes created for 1.0.x, and adds a new archetype descriptor (stored in archetype-metadata.xml file): it's more flexible, has more features,
>     but the basis is absolutely the same.
>
> To create an archetype follow these steps:
>   
> **1.** Create a new project and pom.xml for the archetype artifact
>   
> **2.** Create the archetype descriptor
>   
> **3.** Create the prototype files and the prototype pom.xml
>   
> **4.** Install the archetype and run the archetype plugin

Reference: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

And this is exactly what you want: Maven Archetype for GWT and Spring framework project: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-spring-archetype/
You can see source code, then modify this for newer dependencies.